# How to get my typed result in a custom filter attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my code:

```
// Controller

[HttpGet("{id}")]
[MyFilter]
public async Task<MyCustomType> Load(string id)
{
    return new MyCustomType(....);
}

// Custom attribute

public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Can I have my MyCustomType result here?
    }
}
```

I need to implement some special logic in case of specific property values of MyCustomType result.

Comment: can you explain bit more ?? not able to understand what you want to do !!

Comment: @JawandSingh You see that my action returns an object of MyCustomType. I want to have access to this returned object in my MyFilterAttribute attribute (in OnResultExecuting method)

Comment: tell me are you using MVC `ActionFilterAttribute` ?

Comment: any way i am answering the question assuming that you'll use Web API `ActionFilterAttribute`

Comment: @JawandSingh Look at the code: `public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute`

Comment: look at the method `OnResultExecuting` this not found in web api it is only in MVC

Comment: @JawandSingh AFAIK, in ASP.NET Core there is no difference between MVC project and WebAPI project. User controllers derive from Controller class.

Comment: my bad, just found out that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public class MyCustomType
{
     // assuming that there will be more properties 
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Now, Move to Controller method.

public class CustomController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet({"id"})]
    [MyFilter]
    public async Task<MyCustomType> Load(string id)
    {

       // Do some async operations 
       // Or do some Db queries 
       // returning MyCustomType
       MyCustomType typeToReturn = new MyCustomType();
       typeToReturn.Id = 1;
       typeToReturn.Name = "something";

       return typeToReturn;
    }
} 

 // Well here goes the attribute

public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
     {
          // you have to do more digging i am using dynamic to get the values and result.
          dynamic content = context.Result;
          if (content != null)
          {
              dynamic values = content.Value;
          }

     }

}
```

**EDIT** changed the code and ran it in a dot net core project and i was able to get the values, how ever i have used `dynamic` you can dig more on it.

Comment: more over go through documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#action-filters)

Comment: I think it will work in WebAPI project based on classic ASP.NET framework, but won't in ASP.NET Core. There we have ResultExecutingContext.

Comment: try now i have changed this code to meet your needs and also tested this code for dot net core project.